# SES - Django - Email sent to several people - received by one only

Tags: django, amazon-ses

I'm sending emails to multiple recipients using SES and Django.

The first receiver receives it correctly, not the other ones. I've tried to change the order of the receivers and it's always the first email that receives it. I'm using the same code than for another project where I didn't have any issue... Therefore I suspected an issue with Amazon, but sending from the Amazon console does work fine.

When checking the email received by the first email, I can see that it supposed to be sent to the correct addesses (in the **to** field).

The plain received email is like this (I've removed IPs and IDs and replaced emails with email-number@gmail.com):

```
Delivered-To: EMAIL-1@gmail.com
Received: by ... with SMTP id nXXX;
        Wed, 10 Apr 2013 18:02:18 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by ... with SMTP id XXX;
        Wed, 10 Apr 2013 18:02:17 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <XXX-000000@amazonses.com>
Received: from a8-50.smtp-out.amazonses.com (a8-50.smtp-out.amazonses.com. [...])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id XXX;
        Wed, 10 Apr 2013 18:02:17 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of XXX@amazonses.com designates ... as permitted sender) client-ip=...;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of XXX@amazonses.com designates ... as permitted sender) smtp.mail=XXX@amazonses.com
Return-Path: XXX@amazonses.com
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Subject: Website Enquiry
From: noreply@mydomain.com.au
To: EMAIL1@gmail.com, EMAIL2gmail.com
Date: Thu, 11 Apr 2013 01:02:16 +0000
Message-ID: <XXX@email.amazonses.com>
Reply-To: test@gmail.com
X-SES-Outgoing: 54.240.8.50

Hello,

you have received a message from XXX:

Name: francois
Email: test@gmail.com

test 55
```

As mentioned before, if I reverse To: EMAIL2@gmail.com, EMAIL1gmail.com. EMAIL1 receives the message, not EMAIL2@gmail.com.

The Django code is very basic, just using this:

```
 self.send_email(
            content=self.get_contact_email_content(contact),
            subject='Website Enquiry',
            to=['EMAIL1@gmail.com', 'EMAIL2@gmail.com'],
            reply_to=contact.email_address
        )
```

Same behaviour live and in dev.

I'm clueless.

Comment: try setting `fail_silently=True` and see the `SMTPException` that gets generated

Comment: I think you meant =False (I've just tried both to be sure) - there is no exception generated.

Comment: sorry, i meant `False`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, I was doing:

```
to=['EMAIL1@gmail.com, EMAIL2@gmail.com']
```

instead of:

```
to=['EMAIL1@gmail.com', 'EMAIL2@gmail.com']
```